# Ghostscript convert files from external url

Tags: php, converters, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert an external file (e.g http://url.com/file.ext) using Ghostscript and PHP. It always says undefined filename but if I change the url to my server/local url it works. Is it really possible to convert external file?

```
"C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32.exe" -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -sPAPERSIZE=legal -dBATCH -sOutputFile="C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.tiff" -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER "http://url.com/file.ext"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghostscript doesn't include any browser code. In order to open files i uses the operating system API. If your OS supports opening URLs by using fopen() then it will work, if not, it won't.

Comment: HI. can you please add an example for this?

Comment: I can't see that you need an example, if your OS permits the C library function fopen() to open a remote URL and then fread/fseek/fclose on it, then supplying a URL to Ghostscript on the command line will work. If your OS does not have that functionality, then it won't work. I don't know of any OS which supports fopen on a URL.

Answer (score 2):

For Linux/Unix/macOS users something like this is useful:

```
curl YOUR_URL 2>/dev/null | gs -sOutputFile=%stdout -q ... -
```

Which gets a PDF from stdin and puts the output on stdout.

Just note the ending `-`, in many command line programs that means read from standard input and in here that allows Ghostscript to read the input pdf file from the pipe so you should `-` instead your input file name.

Comment: That worked for us, just keep in mind that the last '-' character is important!

Comment: any complete sample? I got error command failed here

Comment: here's my ghostscript normally (whout external input) gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
-dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf

Comment: @MisterCat, replace that input.pdf with -, just added more description to the answer to show that.